# How to use sed to delete patterns including backslash on MacOS?

Tags: sed, backslash

I'm trying to use sed to delete patterns like "\subsection{sometext}",

so from:

```
Important astrophysical issues could be solved...

\subsection{ Introduction\good line}

\subsection{? apple $ fast burry }white

abc
```

I want:

```
Important astrophysical issues could be solved...

white

abc
```

I have tried:

```
sed -E -i '' 's/\\(section|subsection|subsubsection)\{([^\}]+)\}//g' test.tex
```

but the result is:

```
Important astrophysical issues could be solved...

\subsection{ Introduction\good line}

white

abc
```

It seems that the text including backslash fails to match. I use MacOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`}` inside `[]` does not need escaping, so:

```
's/\\(section|subsection|subsubsection)\{([^}]+)\}//g'
```

simply works.

you could see the rules in `re_format(7)`:

> ... With the exception of these and some combinations using `[' (see next paragraphs), all other special characters, including `\', lose their special significance within a bracket expression.